# Simple Object-oriented Programming Concepts

Tags: java, oop

it may looks like a dummy question for you but I have difficulties solving this:

We have an abstract `class Animal` and `Cat` and `Dog` that extends it. In `Animal` we have a method `produceSound();` that is abstract. As you can probably guess for `Cat` it should return "Mao" and for `Dog` - "Bao" or something like that. This is OK but now we must write a `static` method in the `Animal class` that returns `Cat` or `Dog` objects depending on their sound. For example: `identifyAnimal("Mao")` should return `Cat`.

**Question**: How to implement the `identifyAnimal(String sound)` method?

Here is some simple example of the hierarchy:

**Animal class**

```
public abstract class Animal {

    protected abstract String produceSound();

    protected static void identifyAnimal(String animalSound) {
        // TODO 
    }
}
```

**Cat class**

```
public class Cat extends Animal{

    @Override
    protected String produceSound() {
        return "Mao";
    }
}
```

**Dog class**

```
public class Dog extends Animal{

    @Override
    protected String produceSound() {
        return "Bao";
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
public class AnimalTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal.identifyAnimal("Bao");
    }
}
```

In the `AnimalTest` class when calling the `Animal.identifyAnimal("Bao");` we should get a `Dog`.

Comment: Do you want dog.identifyAnimal("Mao") to return... some instance of Cat or the word Cat? Perhaps dog shouldnt know anything about cat. But if it only knows about "Bao", then you're really asking, boolean dog.isYourSound("Bao");

Static methods aren't on any instance.

Comment: Just wondering, in which country does the cat say Mao and the dog Bao?

Comment: I have just edited the question.

Comment: You say `identifyAnimal` is supposed to be a static method, but you're invoking it as an instance method. I'm not sure what programming language this is, but static methods are usually invoked something like `Animal dog = Animal::identifyAnimal("Bao")`

Comment: But (in your test) you already know that `dog` is a `Dog` because you just instantiated it - does it make sense for a `Dog` instance to be able to identify "Mao"? If `identifyAnimal()` is supposed to be a static method shouldn't it be called as `Animal.identifyAnimal("Bao")`?  (Just out of curiosity, in which language do cats and dogs "Mao" and "Bao"?)

Comment: @Radu in the country south from yours.

Comment: @nnnnnn this is happening a lot isn't it ;)

Comment: I can't think of any elegant way of doing this, other than hardcoding it... `if (sound.equals("Mao")) { return new Cat(); }`... BTW, our cats "Miau" and our dogs "Hau".

Comment: @Radu sorry but this is not the solution that I look for :> There must be a better way

Comment: :D Here we learn the sound of the nature in different languages :D

Comment: I certainly hope so! I'm quite interested in what an elegant solution to this that doesn't involve reflection might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static Class[] animalTypes = [Dog.class, Cat.class];

public static String identifyAnimal(String animalSound)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < animalTypes.length; i++) {
        Animal a = animalTypes[i].newInstance();
        String s = a.produceSound();

        if (animalSound.equals(s))
            return animalTypes[i].getName();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: May be combining yours with the @AdamReed's solution is the golden middle

Answer (score 2):

So here a (terrible) way to do this. I actually twitched a little.
I don't know what language you are using, so I'm going with c++(sorry current mode) though you could replace maps with Dictionaries if we are in C#, whatever. This is a bad way to go about things, but should work(conceptually, anyway)

Again...Terrible...

```
public abstract class Animal {
    
        protected abstract String produceSound();

        protected static map<string, string> SoundList;
        protected static bool registerSound(string sound, string type)
        {
              return (SoundList.insert( pair<string, string>(sound, type)))->second;//true if worked false if already there
              
        }
        
        protected static string identifyAnimal(string animalSound) 
        {
              map<string,string>::iterator result = SoundList.find(sound);
              if(result != SoundList.end())
                   return result->second;
              else
                   return "What The Hell Is This!?";
        }
    }
    Cat class
    
    public class Cat extends Animal
       {
             Cat()
             {
                   Animal::registerSound("Mao","Cat");
             }

        @Override
        protected String produceSound() {
            return "Mao";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just read the Java Tag...would probably go with Manishs solution then

Comment: Or a combo, registering Classes instead of strings. Though this still has the problem of worthless overhead(after first registry/class)

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Animal { 
    static Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    public Animal(String value) { map.put(produceSound(), value); }
    protected abstract String produceSound(); 
    protected static void identifyAnimal(String animalSound) {
        System.out.println(map.get(animalSound));
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override 
    protected String produceSound() { return "Mao"; } 
    Cat(){ super("CAT"); }
}   

class Dog extends Animal { 
    @Override 
    protected String produceSound() { return "Bao"; } 
    Dog(){ super("DOG"); }
}   

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dog();        
        new Cat();
        Animal.identifyAnimal("Bao"); 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a switch with the predefined sounds that you have and let each sound return a string with the name of the animal. For example "Mao" returns a string "Cat" and so on.
One more thing let ur identifyAnimal method returna string instead of void.

Comment: Your method should have a string parameter off course and shouldn't be static I guess

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to get a list of all types that extend Animal, loop through them using Activator to create instances of each type running produceSound on each until you find the return value that matches animalSound, returning that instance. Slow, but effective if you want to avoid your Animal class being aware of what extends it.

Comment: Whoops didn't see the Java tag, I was assuming C#

Answer (score 0):

What is the nature of the problem you are trying to solve? There is no 'right' way that is independent of the problem.

What does the consuming application **need** from the class `Animal`? What does your application need to do with the classes that it consumes? Nothing can be assumed unless these presumptions are clear.